# How to inherit indentation in cell groups?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, cells

In my notebook the text cells "stick out" like this:

[image]

Instead, I'd like the to be left aligned (plus some margin) with the cell they are grouped under... How can I achieve this from the stylesheet?

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"], CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 60}]
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `ItemParagraph`, instead, (and `SubitemParagraph` and `SubsubitemParagram` as needed), as it is built specifically for this purpose.

Comment: But I would prefer this behavior by default, and I don't want to switch the default cel type from Text, (and Ive run out of menu command keys to use)

Comment: Have you used `!@#$%^&*()`, yet? That said, I am looking for a solution; `Inherited` does not seem to want to cooperate.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I'd rather not have to remember yet another key lol

Comment: I feel your pain. I tend to closely modify cell styles, so that if I want the alternate, I just add shift.

Comment: @rcollyer & M.R. I don't think it can be done with only Text style. Paragraphs have their Margins hardcoded in Default.nb to match items, subitems etc. I would imagine that it'd have been done with Inherited otherwise.

Comment: @Kuba I'm aware. Although, some use Inherited ...

Comment: I have this related question I'm having trouble with if you happen be interested or have time.   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255831/how-to-dynamically-update-cellframe-around-1-2-or-more-cells-of-the-same-style

Answer (score 4):

You can give "Text" cells the option `CellMargins -> AbsoluteCurrentValue[PreviousCell[], CellMargins]` in your stylesheet. Here's a pic of a notebook using this option for Text cells:

[image]

**Addendum**

It seems that for versions before M12 you need to include a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) wrapper. So, use:

```
CellMargins -> Dynamic @ AbsoluteCurrentValue[PreviousCell[], CellMargins]
```

or perhaps even better:

```
CellMargins -> Dynamic @ AbsoluteCurrentValue[PreviousCell[CellStyle -> {"Section", "Subsection"}], CellMargins]
```

Comment: That will fail if e.g. Output figures are inserted between paragraphs but +1 anyway.

Comment: Probably better to use ``CellMargins -> {{FEPrivate`Part[FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[FrontEnd`PreviousCell[], CellMargins], 1, 1], Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}`` no? Only the lateral margin should be pulled from above.