# Automatic indentation of text and equations depending on Style

Tags: notebooks, style, stylesheet, automation

I have a rule when writing text and equations. Starting from the `Section` environment, each text/equation that sits inside `Section` will get indexed by one Tab. Anything that lives inside a `Subsection` gets a further Tab (i.e. 2 Tabs) and so on.
Now, as I expand my notebook, sometimes Sections become Subsections or vice-versa, meaning that I need to go back and correct all the indentations manually.
Is there a way to automate this?

Carl Woll's answer to add a dynamic wrapper such as,

> CellMargins -> Dynamic[ AbsoluteCurrentValue[ PreviousCell[CellStyle->{"Section","Subsection"}], CellMargins]]

works. However, Mathematica becomes rather laggy. I am assuming it is because Mathematica keeps checking each line of text all the time. Ideally, it would only do that once (e.g. when the Stylesheet is selected as it does so with the above code) and anytime a grouping occurs or when a Style environment (e.g. via Alt+ (1-6)) is created.
This sounds a bit complicated, so alternatively, it is fine if a button is created that sorts the selected grouping as desired.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197356/45431) help?

Comment: Thank you. I tried implementing both suggestions, but I get many error messages, all saying: "The specified setting for the option CellMargins cannot be used."

Comment: What's your Mathematica version and OS?

Comment: I am working on Linux x86 (64-bit Ubuntu) with Mathematica 11.3.0.0

Comment: Looks like it only works on M12, and it still issues messages there too.

Comment: Does adding a Dynamic wrapper fix things for you? For example `CellMargins -> Dynamic[
   AbsoluteCurrentValue[
    PreviousCell[CellStyle->{"Section","Subsection"}], CellMargins]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a button that can do this for you. I put it in a docked cell:

```
With[{styles = {"Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection"}},
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
        DockedCells -> Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Button[
            "align",
            Map[
                Set[
                    CurrentValue[#, {CellMargins,1,1}],
                    CurrentValue[PreviousCell[#, CellStyle->styles], {CellMargins,1,1}]
                ]&,
                Cells[CellStyle->"Text"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

You could also put the button in a palette. A short animation:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. If I want to slightly tweak the placement of the text with respect to the environment, what part of this code needs to be altered? For example, if I wanted the text to be aligned with the title as it does here + a few spaces, how can I do that?
Also, does this also work with Code? (by replacing the "Text" with "Code" I guess)

Comment: @Patrick.B To adjust the alignment, modify the RHS of the `Set` (e.g., `5 + CurrentValue[..]`). To make it work with "Code" cells as well, use `CellStyle->{"Text", "Code"}`.