# How to Dynamically update CellFrame around 1, 2 or more cells of the same style (Looking for a Stylesheet Solution)

Tags: options, stylesheet

The following "Theorem" cellstyle in defined in my private stylesheet

```
Cell[StyleData["Theorem"],
 CellFrame->{{.5,.5},{.5,.5}},
 CellMargins->{{40, 10}, {7, 7}}]
```

I would like to modify this definition so that the CellFrame and CellMargins options dynamically update depending on the number of cells of this style that are back-to-back in the notebook.  For a visual, the desired behavior is shown below:

[image]

I have tried incorporating the CurrentValue[] function in the CellFrame and CellMargin options above to pull in data from adjacent cells above and below the current cell in the hopes of using the data, but haven't been able to get very far at all.  Although, it seems like this is the way to go.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related to 
related to: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234486/can-a-style-inherit-cellmargins-depending-how-it-is-grouped

 and 

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/how-to-inherit-indentation-in-cell-groups